# Get mobile GeoLocation in .Net Core web app

Tags: web-services, web-applications, .net-core, geolocation, gps

I want to develop a `.Net Core web app` that will run on mobile phones. This app needs to detect the mobile geo location for tracking the user location.

Both server and client sides of this app should run on the mobile phone; i.e. the server side is just a logic layer in the app, not a separate app. Since this should be a tiny app, I want to remove the need of maintaining a separate server and use the client resources for that, so all what the user needs is a mobile app without connecting to a server.

I understood that there is no currently `GPS` API support in `.Net Core`, so I thought to consume some web service for doing that.

I googled a lot but couldn't find such web service that I can use (without adding uncommon dependency that will have to be installed on the mobile as well).

Is this way a good practice? or there is a better solution? If it is- what web service can I use?

Answer (score 5):

The .NET Core Web Application runs on the server side - the mobile phone is the client of your webapplication and will likley display the HTML result in the browsers. So to detect the GeoLocation you will use e.g. JavaScript and the [HTML5 GeoLocation API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

```
<script>
 function getLocation() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPos);
   } else {
     alert("Geolocation is not supported by browser");
   }
 }

 function showPos(position) {
   alert("Lat: " + position.coords.latitude +  " Long: " + position.coords.longitude); 
 }
</script>
```