# How can I calculate distance between users using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am creating a learning site.

How can I get the geographical distance between people on the site using IP ADDRESS with ASP.NET Core 5 ?

Comment: Consider to use the Geolocation API: [Get mobile GeoLocation in .Net Core web app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481023/6630084)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find distance between 2 coordinates in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700865/find-distance-between-2-coordinates-in-net-core)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackdaw's comment is useful, you can ask permission to get users's location, then you can calculate the distance.

---

And you also can [get user location by ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327629/get-user-location-by-ip-address). Through the service of a third party, the latitude and longitude can be obtained, and then the position information can be obtained for calculation.

[Find distance between 2 coordinates in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700865/find-distance-between-2-coordinates-in-net-core)

[image]